# Save matrix to file given in variable

Tags: matlab, octave

What I want to do is very simple. This works:

```
save weights.txt weights
```

but this does not:

```
filename = "weights.txt"
save filename weights
```

Well, it does save the matrix `weights` but to a file named `filename` ... not `weights.txt`.

I've tried

```
save("-ascii", filename, "weights");
```

but it's awful, since the name of the matrix has to be a string. Moreover this doesn't work. Octave says it can't convert a NDArray (?) to a Matrix.

Why? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dlmwrite` for writing delimited ASCII data:

```
>> filename = "weights.txt";
>> weights = rand(3,3);
>> dlmwrite(filename, weights)
>> type weights.txt

0.16218,0.52853,0.26297
0.79428,0.16565,0.65408
0.31122,0.60198,0.68921
```

By default this is comma-delimited, but you can pass your own delimiter as the third argument.

#### Edit:

Well, MATLAB will let you save arrays of any dimensions with `dlmwrite`, and you can read the data back with `dlmread`. But, as carandraug points out, the ASCII representation will be at most 2D (MATLAB will flatten the extra dimensions). You can still recover this information if you also save the shape of the exported matrix somewhere:

```
>> shape = "shape.txt";
>> weights = rand(3,3,3);
>> dlmwrite(filename, weights, 'precision', 17)
>> dlmwrite(shape, size(weights))
>> M = reshape(dlmread(filename), dlmread(shape));
>> all(M(:) == weights(:))
ans =
     1
```

This is, of course, a little cumbersome compared to just using MATLAB's native `save weights; load weights`.

Comment: All I need is to save a very large, N-dimensional matrix that takes a lot of time to compute. Could you supply a complete solution how to save/load such a matrix?

Comment: This intention was not really clear from your question "Save matrix to file given in variable", but see my edit. I assumed you needed the ASCII data somewhere outside MATLAB/Octave; if this not the case, I would suggest the native `save`/`load` to avoid issues with loss of information, as described by carandraug.

Comment: I dont need ASCII - I need only persistance. Bu I really need to save the matrix to a file given in a variable. It's a very basic task, the name of the file contains e.g. the current time.

Comment: You can still do this the way you tried: `save(filename, 'weights')`, where `filename` is a string variable, but unfortunately the array name will need to be enclosed in quotes. There is no way around this except what's in my answer, or by using MATLAB's `matfile` function, which I doubt Octave supports.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 problems there:

1. *use `save` as command and pass a variable or as function but not passing the variable names as strings*. There's no way around this. The way the command form works is by transforming every argument to a string. When you do `save weights.txt weights` this is interpreted as `save ("weights.txt", "weights")` and when you do `save filename weights` it's the same as `save ("filename", "weights")` hence why it saves in a file named filename. And why do you have to pass the variable name in a string rather than the variable itself? Imagine that the variable you are trying to save is a string. How would `save` know if it should save the string or a variable named as the string?
2. *save an NDArray with `-ascii` option*. You can't do this, you'll need to use another format. If you want it to be in a text file, use `-text` instead of `ascii`. text is a format that also saves information about the matrix dimensions so matrices of any sized can be saved and loaded correctly. In ascii format all that information is lost so any matrix with more than 2 dimensions will fail. Try `x = rand (3); save -ascii x_ascii.txt x; save -text x_text.txt x` and look inside the files to see the difference. Could you think of a way to save `x` as ascii if it was a 3D matrix?